# How do I use a record in a Query that is not the RecordSource in conditional statements?

Tags: ms-access, vba

First off, I am relatively new to `Access` and `VBA`, and while I have some good understanding of things I'm still not too familiar with the underlying concepts that access and `VBA` use.

I have two queries, Tuning and Hardware (the database is for a CNC machining line). Tuning is the Record Source for the form. I use data in the Tuning query in conditional statements to colour code boxes on the form depending on their values. A sample of this is in my code is:

```
If MachineID = 3 And (Integral_Gain_X < 181 Or Integral_Gain_Y < 181 Or 
Integral_Gain_Z < 195) Then
m110a.BackColor = RGB(247, 255, 0)
End If
```

(`Integral_Gain_X` is a field in Tuning)

I want to have a similar type of statement that uses data entries from a field in the Hardware query to make similar types of conditional statements, but have been not been able to do so. Is it possible, and if so could you explain the best way to go about setting this up?

Please let me know if this is enough information, it is my first post on here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: we'll need to see the Hardware query, also which version of ms access?

Comment: you can use DLOOKUP to lookup values in Hardware using criteria from Tuning

Answer (score 0):

DLOOKUP will get a single value from another table or query with criteria taken from the current record displayed.

However, if you need to get a lot of fields from another table it can be a slow method, but this is only usually a factor when multiple records are displayed on a list form.

Another option is to base your form on a query that selects data from the two queries Tuning and Hardware, joined together.  This will be quicker than using DLOOKUP.  This doesn't always work  as adding some joins will cause the query to be "un-updatable".  Best thing to do is try creating a new query selecting from the two queries, ensuring the joins are done so that only one row is ever fond in the hardware table for a single row in the tuning table.

(Use a OUTERJOIN (eg LEFT JOIN), to always get the tuning rows even when no hardware row exists).

If either table has a group by clause (ie with SUM, MIN, MAX) you won't be able to do this as group by statements are always un-updateable)

Also be aware that later versions of Access can have conditional formatting rules added to a field (very much like in excel) open a form in design view. See ribbon>Form Design>Format>Conditional formatting.

PS.  I would expect the VBA IF statement you gave to have an else that sets the colour back